# How to fake a USB flash drive's capacity?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, storage

I was wondering how to make a 30 GB flash drive  appear as if it is 2 TB (prank for a friend). I am not experienced in coding, so, can someone tell me the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Well there is your problem.  You need to start with only a 4gb drive...

Comment: Not a direct answer but: The most practical way to get one of these is probably just buy a drive of the desired capacity that's unreasonably cheap on ebay.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way I know is to change the flash controller with custom chip so when computer ask for the total amount of memory it report very big number. Also this chip (usually) do cyclic write operations so when you write more than real amount of memory it continue from the begin and do not return a error (disk full for example). And usually these flash memories are formatted on special way to mislead the operating system.

Comment: If you rewrite the partition table and repartition it, will you be able to tell there's something wrong with the initial stated capacity? (I'm not wanting to prank a friend. I'm just curious how to identify a fake capacity here.)

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx, this may help you to recognize fake storage. But the best is to copy big amount of data and check after copy the checksums from this storage